# How to set the minimum acl permissions for an user who is included in two or more user groups with different permissions in linux?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, access-control-list

Say, I have two groups G1 and G2 with user1 as member to both. G1 has rwx permission on a file file1 and G2 has only read permission on the same file. Setting G2 as the primary group for user1 does not prevent it from having rwx permissions on file1. I wish to use acl to allow user1 to the have only G2's permissions(The minimum in this case), i.e. r-- while being a member of both the groups G1 and G2. Is it possible? I am using RHEL7.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [access control lists](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-acls.html) and setting up per user permissions

Comment: Not exactly. I want user1 to have r-- permission only because that is the lowest or most restricted set available among all the groups user1 is a member of. I can set explicit r-- permission on user1 but that I wish to avoid. Is it possible for any user which is part of multiple groups to have the same permissions as the most restricted group it belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for any user which is part of multiple groups to have the same permissions as the most restricted group it belongs to?

No, it is not possible. Since user1 can get larger permission via group G1, these are the final permissions that apply. Any different behavior would break the permission system. For instance, imagine adding all users of a system to a dummy group which has 0 permission to all files on the machine.

You might want to remove access to file1 from G1 and G2 and set up ACLs, or remove user1 from G1.